# how to avoid duplicating JTable columns in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

i want to add a cloumn to a jtable when a radio button is being clicked. but when i click it twice two columns are being added to the table. here's my code

```
 dtm = (DefaultTableModel) viewTable.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    TableColumnModel model=viewTable.getColumnModel();
    boolean found=false;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if (model.getColumn(i).getIdentifier().equals("customer Id")) {
            found=true;
            break;
        }


    if (found==false) {
       dtm.addColumn("customer Id");

    }
```

don't know how to fix it..

Comment: If it's a radio button, you should be able to detect if the state is `selected` or not, removing the column when unselected and adding when selected...

Comment: Your code appears to be missing a very significant closing brace `}`

Comment: Also you can try with the `getValueAt` method.

Comment: and next time pls post the whole method... otherwise we may dont understand in which context we are. The more you post of your code the more we understand whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would help you. Call the below method on actionPerformed of the check box and if it is true. Validating it based on the column header.

```
private static void addColumn( final JTable table, final String newColumnHeader )
{
    final JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    final int columnCount = header.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();
    boolean addColumn = true;
    for( int index = 0; index < columnCount; index ++ )
    {
        final Object headerValue = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).getHeaderValue();
        if( newColumnHeader.equals( headerValue ) )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Column already exists" );
            addColumn = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( addColumn )
    {
        final TableColumn newCol = new TableColumn();
        newCol.setHeaderValue(newColumnHeader);
        table.getColumnModel().addColumn(newCol);
    }

}
```

It is good to disable the checkbox if it is already clicked ;) if you do not want a huge code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clumsy solution but it will work.

You can create a new boolean variable in your class and this variable represents if a column was set or not.
Like:

```
class MyClass{
    boolean isColumnAdded

    public MyClass(){
    isColumnAdded = false;
    }

    private void radioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        if(!isColumnAdded){
        //add column
        isColumnAdded = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `JRadioButton` is a descendant of `AbstractButton`, buttons should never be triggered through the use of `MouseListener` and should rely on an `ActionListener`, as there is more than one way that they can triggered.  A `JRadioButton` already has a `selected` state property, which should be checked to determine what action should be taken. Sorry but this is both misleading and wrong...

Comment: this is not a full implementation. This code example shall show how you can resolve this issue. I know your statements but i wrote this code example on the fly. The OP does not give us the context in which method he is so i barely guess.. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

To start with, `JRadioButton` has a `selected` property.  You should be checking this state to determine if the column needs to be removed or added...

Assume that each column name is unique, you could use something like...

```
TableColumnModel model = viewTable.getColumnModel();
int index = -1;
try {
    index = model.getColumnIndex("customer Id");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // I know, sucks...
}
if (index < 0) {
    // Add new column, if JRadioButton.isSelected
} else {
    // Remove old column...
    // JRadioButton.isSelected is false...
}
```

To find and add/remove the column.

Have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for some more details